# PHP: How to check if preg_replace match is within a specified HTML tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm creating a type of bulk/dynamic linking plugin for Wordpress in which a person can dynamically create links within posts based on matching words (for SEO, etc.). Like so:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'atg_generate_links');
function atg_generate_links($content) {
    if (is_single()) {
        $pattern = '/(Christmas gifts)/i';
        $replacement = "<a href='#' target='_self'>$1</a>";
        return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

I do *not* want to match text found within `<h1>`-`<h6>` tags or within `<a>` tags (to prevent nested anchor tags). How can I check to see if the `preg_replace` matches are found within those, or other specific, tags?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You shouldn't be using _preg*_ for parsing html...

Comment: That's not my question, but what should I be using?

Comment: I am aware this was not your question...you should be thankful for hints instead of complaining...take a look at [htmlparsing](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html)

Comment: `$pattern = '/<(a|h[1-6])(?:\s[^>]*)?>[^<]*<\/1>(*SKIP)(*F)|Christmas gifts/i';` and instead of `$1` use `$0`.

Comment: Not "complaining," mind you. Note that I did not ask how to parse html with regex. At this point I have only searched for a single text phrase. I am *asking* how do determine if its in those tags, whatever might be the best method.